# error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'char *(__cdecl *)(int,int)' to en 'GetItemText_t'

Tags: c++, c

I get an error in a code( the code isn't mine,it was just released on an other website)

I get this error :

error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'char *(__cdecl *)(int,int)' to en 'GetItemText_t'

Here is the code :

```
char* TheatreMenu_GetItemText(int index, int column)
{
    if( index >= 0 && index < uiDemoInfo.numDemos)
    {
        switch(column)
        {
        case 0:
            return uiDemoInfo.demos.at(index).demoName;
            break;
        case 1:
            return UI_LocalizeMapName(uiDemoInfo.demos.at(index).mapName);
            break;
        }
    }
    return "";
}

void PatchMW2_TheatreMenu()
{
    TheatreMenu_Feeder.feeder = 10.0f;
    TheatreMenu_Feeder.GetItemCount = TheatreMenu_GetItemCount;
    TheatreMenu_Feeder.GetItemText = TheatreMenu_GetItemText;
    TheatreMenu_Feeder.Select = TheatreMenu_Select;

    UIFeeders.push_back(TheatreMenu_Feeder);

    AddUIScript("loadDemos", TheatreMenu_UIScript_LoadDemos);
    AddUIScript("FixDemoServer", TheatreMenu_UIScript_FixDemoServer);
    AddUIScript("LaunchDemo", TheatreMenu_UIScript_LaunchDemo);

    strcpy((char*)(0x6FB620), "oldrec");
    strcpy((char*)(0x708238), "oldstoprec"); 

    Cmd_AddCommand("record", customRecordFunc, &customRecord, 0);
    Cmd_AddCommand("stoprecord", customStopRecordFunc, &customStopRecord, 0);
}
```

The error is from this line :

```
TheatreMenu_Feeder.GetItemText = TheatreMenu_GetItemText;
```

I hope you will help me quickly,
thanks in advance.

Cordially,
Chris

Comment: How have you declared `TheatreMenu_Feeder.GetItemText`

Comment: Is there any typedef resulting in type GetItemText_t?

Comment: How can we be expected to know what the problem is when you haven't even shown us what `GetItemText_t` is? Contrary to popular belief, we are not psychics. The most we can say is what the error already says.

Comment: Here is the whole code : http://iw4mtoolkit.sourceforge.net/mods/theatremenu/PatchMW2TheatreMenu.cpp

Comment: @user3287874 No, the whole code is not there. The included header files, necessary to give a useful answer, are not there.

Answer (score 0):

`TheatreMenu_GetItemText` is a function name, I'm not sure the type of `TheatreMenu_Feeder.GetItemText` because `UIFeeder_t TheatreMenu_Feeder;` while you hadn't support the definition of `UIFeeder_t`.

what makes this error ? You may check the `UIFeeder_t.GetItemText`'s definition.Is it same as `TheatreMenu_GetItemText`'s definition ?

---

BTW , about this function .

```
char* TheatreMenu_GetItemText(int index, int column)
{
    if( index >= 0 && index < uiDemoInfo.numDemos)
    {
        switch(column)
        {
        case 0:
            return uiDemoInfo.demos.at(index).demoName;
            break;
        case 1:
            return UI_LocalizeMapName(uiDemoInfo.demos.at(index).mapName);
            break;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

the final line ,I think `return NULL` may better. Of course , if here changed , some related code may need corresponding change

Comment: All string literals in both C and C++ have always had static storage duration: they exist throughout the entire program, even after the function returns.

Comment: Sorry to have replied now but i just modified it to const char* function type and it worked,thanks anyway;)